# How to extract deeply nested array of objects and move to React Hook state?

Tags: javascript

I have one array of 49 objects in total. Inside each nested object, there is another nested "**children**" array. And inside this array, there is a value of "**text**".

I am trying to map and filter out these values only, to concat/combine the text and move them to my React Hook. This way I am left with only text so I can calculate the reading time based on the amount of textual content.

My Hook:

```
const [textSize, setTextSize] = useState();
```

4 out of 49 objects example:

```
0: {_key: 'ade9a24f5cb6', _type: 'block', caption: null, children: Array(1), markDefs: Array(0), …}
1: {_key: '5aa8a2fa2969', _type: 'block', caption: null, children: Array(1), markDefs: Array(0), …}
2: {_key: '602703f9c2b7', _type: 'block', caption: null, children: Array(1), markDefs: Array(0), …}
3: {_key: '211597e8045a', _type: 'block', caption: null, children: Array(1), markDefs: Array(0), …}
```

Inside one of the "children" array:

```
0: {_key: '76f4ec1ed87f', _type: 'span', marks: Array(0), text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'}
```

and from that array, I need the text of each object if that makes sense?

***Array has 49 objects => Each object has nested Array (children) => Each children array has value "text".***

Comment: Do you want to have an array of texts ?

Comment: This is not really related to React - you'll just need a regular JavaScript function that walks a tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this? If I'm understanding your problem correctly..

```js
let array = [
  {_key: 'ade9a24f5cb6', _type: 'block', caption: null, children: [
    {_key: '76f4ec1ed87f', _type: 'span', marks: Array(0), text: '1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'},
    {_key: '76f4ec1ed87f', _type: 'span', marks: Array(0), text: '2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'}
  ], markDefs: Array(0) },
  {_key: '5aa8a2fa2969', _type: 'block', caption: null, children: [
    {_key: '76f4ec1ed87f', _type: 'span', marks: Array(0), text: '3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'}
  ], markDefs: Array(0) },
  {_key: '602703f9c2b7', _type: 'block', caption: null, children: [
    {_key: '76f4ec1ed87f', _type: 'span', marks: Array(0), text: '4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'},
    {_key: '76f4ec1ed87f', _type: 'span', marks: Array(0), text: '5 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'},
    {_key: '76f4ec1ed87f', _type: 'span', marks: Array(0), text: '6 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'},
  ], markDefs: Array(0) },
  {_key: '211597e8045a', _type: 'block', caption: null, children: [], markDefs: Array(0) }
]

let results = array.map(x => x.children).flat().map(y => y.text);
console.log(results);
```